How to load a image from a nested JSON file into react along with other content
I have recently encountered a problem while trying to load a image from my nested JSON file. the image is loaded along with other JSON content in a accordion but for some reason the image loads with another accordion but it should load in the related accordion not make another one
this is the related part of my JSX code that renders the image
const renderImage = (key, value) => {
        if (key === 'ImgUrl' && typeof value === 'string') {
            return (
                <OverlayTrigger
                    key={value}
                    placement="bottom"
                    overlay={
                        <Popover id={`popover-positioned-bottom`}>
                            <Popover.Header as="h3" className={Styles.PopoverHeader}>{facts.title}</Popover.Header>
                            <Popover.Body>
                                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
                            </Popover.Body>
                        </Popover>
                    }
                >
                    <Figure key={value}>
                        <Figure.Image
                            width={500}
                            height={300}
                            alt="Image"
                            src={value}
                        />
                        <Figure.Caption>{facts.title}</Figure.Caption>
                    </Figure>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            );
        }
        return null;
    };

    const renderContent = (content, level = 2) => {
        if (typeof content === 'string') {
            return <p>{content}</p>;
        }

        if (typeof content === 'object' && content !== null) {
            return Object.entries(content).map(([key, value]) => {
                const HeadingTag = `h${level}`;
                return (
                    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" key={key} data-bs-theme="dark">
                        <Accordion.Item eventKey={key}>
                            <Accordion.Header><HeadingTag>{key}</HeadingTag></Accordion.Header>
                            <Accordion.Body>
                                {key === 'ImgUrl' && typeof value === 'string' ? (
                                    renderImage(key, value)
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        {renderContent(value, level + 1)}
                                        {typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && value.ImgUrl && renderImage('ImgUrl', value.ImgUrl)}
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </Accordion.Body>
                        </Accordion.Item>
                    </Accordion>
                );
            });
        }

        return null;
    };

    return (
        <section className={Styles.FactDetailsBody}>
            <Row className={Styles.MainRow}>
                <Col sm={12}>
                    <h1>{facts.title}</h1>
                    {renderContent(facts.Overview)}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </section>
    );

and this is the structure of my JSON file
"Overview": {
                "Overview and Introduction": "The Tiger I (German: [ˈtiːɡɐ]) was a German heavy tank used extensively in World War II. .",
                
                "ImgUrl":"path/to/my/image;
                 "Development History": {
                    "Early Development",
                    "Breakthrough with VK 45.01"
                },
                "Design Specifications": {
                    "Armor and Protection": "The Tiger I was designed with substantial armor to           withstand enemy fire. The frontal hull a

and with this i get a result like this
what the result looks like
what I'm trying to get
and so every image is loaded within their related accordion and the image should not have a accordion of it self

That is because you are rendering the titles based on the key of the facts.Overview object, so when a (key, value) pair is "imgUrl":"someRef" , you render the imgUrl as the header and the image as the body. You need to change your code handling this cases.
You need to render an Acordion if the key is not imgUrl. Then, after processing every key (which will not be imgUrl) you need to look for JSON keys named imgUrl and render their values inside the current Acordion body.
